# What Database to use for a network share?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I need help picking a database to use for an application I am writing. Basically I am writing an application that will have about 5-10 users accessing the database to input values, generate reports, or simply to look up information. We are currently using Microsoft Access, but VBA is horrible and I am wanting to rewrite the application in C#.

I need a database that allows multiple users at once. Currently the access database is on a network share, but if there is a better way to do this I am all for it.

Everyone that uses the application has the ability to install anything on their computers. I am however on a network that I don't have permission to change settings on. In this scenario I was thinking about using SQL Express, but without a dedicated server I don't know how this will work and SQLlite doesn't really support, multiuser access on a network, and I really hate MS access.

Comment: *"without a dedicated server"* - Then where is the network share currently hosted?  Is one of the workstations acting as an ad-hoc server?  I suppose nothing would technically be lost of that same workstation became the SQLExpress host, though having a non-workstation dedicated server is definitely preferred.  (Understand that there's nothing special about a "server."  Any computer will do.  It's just a matter of not having users on it all the time doing things that may break or require reboots, etc.)

Comment: Yea the Network share is hosted on a server, but I don't have access to modify it. All I can modify are the machines the users are on and my application. I wasn't sure if it would be ok to install sqlExpress on one of them then just connect the others to it, but that has to be better than running Access though.

Comment: Using any user's workstation as an ad-hoc server won't be a good idea.  (Just think of random reboots that corrupt other people's transactions.)  So, you've been using a server, but you don't have access to modify it?  Who does?  It sounds like you should be putting in a request with somebody.  Are you just trying to "sneak this in" without properly including it in the network infrastructure?  If so, you can't really rely on it for anything.  Someone might notice unexpected traffic on unexpected ports and firewall you out of your database.  Best to go through proper channels.

Comment: I haven't been using a server at all they are using Access and I am trying to upgrade to a proper database. I'm not really trying to sneak this in. Its for a university and the department I am doing this project for wants this database done, but they don't have a dedicated server for a database and the admins that control the university database won't let me have access to it.

Comment: Visual Foxpro is a great multi-user database and development language for what you are describing. However, if you are going to rewrite this in C#, then look at SQL Server CE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by David I am just going to put in a request with the university Computer Services and request a SQL Server database.